# How to connect Microsoft Live Writer to write blogs on IBM Connections 4.5?

Tags: ibm-connections, windows-live-writer, metaweblog

Using [this](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/dx/10142009104123AMWEBK8Y.htm) description from IBM Connections 4.5, I try to get Microsoft Live Writer (from the Windows Essentials 2012 package) to connect to Connections 4.5. My Connections blog does have the BlogClient API setting activated, but I can't seem to get my settings right.

As my blog URL I use the full URL to the connection blog at the format

```
https://<connections url>/blogs/0f787572-d8f8-4932-9e82-2ce047b1a9b7
```

Then I enter my username and password, and click Next. I choose "Metaweblog API" as my blogtype and use the following as the URL:

```
https://<connections url>/blogs/services/xmlrpc
```

When I click next, I only get an instant answer that my username or password is wrong. Does anybody see any errors in the specification above?

Comment: hi Bob, have you referred to this article? http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/dx/11272008035302PMWEBSH7.htm

Comment: Hi Paul! I have just tried this and can verify that those steps works on my Word 2010 version. But only raw text. As soon as I post a blog with pasted- or imported images, the interface complain about not being able to upload images. In the blog-settings (Manage Accounts) I see a button titled "Image alternatives" (I am not 100% certain of the translation here, and have just translated directly from Norwegian), I see that I can choose "My blog service", "my own server" or "none". I have chosen the first. Any ideas on how to transfer images too?

Comment: I think it said it did not yet support images... I'm not sure.

Comment: Paul, you are right! The last paragraphs says so! That is exactly why I like Live Writer so much better. Easier to work with, very blog-focus, and it has been working (also with pasted and imported images) with the old and trusted BlogSphere template from Declan for many years now.